# Retrieval Of Dax Query From Visuals in Embedded Power Bi Project

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I Am Working On Embedded Power BI Project. There Are Many Visuals In Power BI. I Want To Get DAX QUERY Of That Particular Visuals. How Can I Get It....?

```
async function getTableVisualDaxQuery(visual) {
    try {
        // Export data from the visual
        const exportDataResult = await visual.exportData('models', 'display');

        // Check if the exportDataResult object contains any data models
        if (exportDataResult?.dataModels) {
            // Extract the DAX query from the exported data
            const daxQuery = exportDataResult?.dataModels?.[0]?.daxQuery;

            return daxQuery;
        } else {
            // The exportDataResult object does not contain any data models
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error getting DAX query for ${visual.name}:`, error);
        return null;
    }
}

try {
    const pages = await report.getPages();
    // Retrieve the page that contain the visual. For the sample report it will be the active page
    let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
        return page.isActive
    })[0];

    const visuals = await page.getVisuals();

    const tableVisuals = visuals.filter(function (visual) {
        return visual.type === "pivotTable";
    });

    const visualsWithDaxQueries = await Promise.all(
        tableVisuals.map(async function (tableVisual) {
            const daxQuery = await getTableVisualDaxQuery(tableVisual);
            return {
                name: tableVisual.name,
                type: tableVisual.type,
                title: tableVisual.title,
                layout: tableVisual.layout,
                daxQuery: daxQuery
            };
        })
    );

    console.log(visualsWithDaxQueries);

}
catch (errors) {
    console.log(errors);
}
```

You Can Referrer All This Stuff On Powerbi

https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox

I Tried To Get Dax Query Of Visuals From Embedded Power Bi Report But I Can Not Get DaxQuery. I Am Expecting To Get Dax Query From Visuals.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that is possible.

https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/blob/master/dist/powerbi.js#L12811

That function just accepts the type of export, undelying or summarized and how many rows.

This does not look valid: `visual.exportData('models', 'display');`